# Is it possible (reasonable) to expose a SOAP WS as JMS?

Tags: web-services, architecture, jms

If so, what would be the message like? An XML document with the SOAP request or response?

Does this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish thinks so:

https://jms-ws-transport.dev.java.net/

An asynch message would imply either no response or a simple ACK ("We got your message; we'll get back to you.") to me.

Comment: but isn't this the other way around (ws on JMS)? Of course, I'm not 100% what the original question meant but... :)

Comment: You can certainly do it either - it's just a question of choices.  Personally, I think using JMS should be an implementation detail, hidden from clients.